# Глобальные переменные

Tags: c++

Имею классы A, B, C и класс L.

Класс L при инициализации открывает\создает файл.

Вызовом `L->Out("Log here");` я выкидываю лог в файл.

Каким наиболее рациональным способом можно сделать так, чтобы объект класса L был доступен в A, B и C без повторной инициализации и переоткрытия файла?

Comment: Комментарий в ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Синглтон?](http://cpp-reference.ru/patterns/creational-patterns/singleton/)

Answer (score 2):

Например, сделайте экземпляр доступным глобально.

В конце `l.cpp`:

```
L g_logger("параметры", "инициализации");
```

В `l.h`:

```
extern L g_logger;
```

В начале `a.cpp`

```
#include "l.h"
```

Comment: В комментариях указано то, что мне нужно :)

Answer (score 2):

Необходимо понимать время жизни объектов A, B, C и L. Инициировать L так, чтобы он существовал все время жизни использующих его объектов. Передавать в них можно хоть ссылкой в конструктор.

Сделать L глобальным - частный вариант этого решения.

Я бы не рекомендовал использовать синглтон.

Comment: Почему не рекомендуете?
Если вы от чего то отказываетесь, то, предлагайте альтернативу. Ссылка в конструктор - это просто, но не удобно и порождает лишний код. А синглтон отлично подходит для моей задачи.

Comment: Так и есть несколько альтернатив, глобальная переменная или передача по ссылке/умный указатель. 
Почему ссылка в конструктор не удобно - я не понимаю. Проблемы же у синглтона следующие: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons , в ответах перечислено множество примеров. Да, делая L глобальным, часть этих проблем мы тянем так же, но не все, и код получается проще. А передавая ссылкой (в A, B, C можно хранить ссылку на L, инициализированную в конструкторе), мы делаем все аккуратно, читабельно и без недостатков. Почему это не удобно - не знаю :)